# Conversion failed error when it shouldn't be trying to convert anything

Tags: entity-framework, csv, parsing, type-conversion, dbset

Message "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '\"United States\"' to data type int."

I use entity framework for data access to a SQL DB.

It is set as a string in my table and it is set as a string in my entity.

This is happening in a CSV parsing programme, when trying to call the save changes method of the DbSet.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this problem?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept it to indicate that the question is answered. (Click on the checkmark beside the answer.)

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to do that in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you havent made changes on your database? If so, run 
    UpdateDatabase

in your PM console. If not, check the parsing of the CSV columns. Maybe you're mapping them wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I'd forgotten to do that